# prestashop user login integration

Tags: symfony, authentication, integration, prestashop

I have to integrate PrestaShop 1.5 with pre-existing symfony application.

Through webservices, I can keep the databases in sync so a user can perform login with the same data on both PrestaShop and application software.
Now I want to to ensure that logging in application, the user is automatically logged in the PrestaShop platform.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hello, Prestashop 1.4 or 1.5 ?

Comment: 1.5 as I wrote thank you

Comment: Old question for sure but one could have a look at this, https://github.com/hparfr/prestashopBridge

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still searching for a solution but there is a way actually.

**DO MAKE SURE IT IS A SECURE LOGIN.**

Since you're giving access to all prestashop data do make sure the login is very secure. I've been able to recreate it with `PHP` I think that with some additions you're able to recreate it the way you want it. See it as a guideline.

To create a login system by using the prestashop webservice you'll need three things

Access through webservice to the customers table
The COOKIE_KEY, defined in app/config -> parameters.php:: 'cookie_key' => '12321test';
Some expierence with PHP
The first thing is to get the customers table from the webservice.

```
// code placeholder
require_once('./../PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/**
 * get information from PrestaShop
 */

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

$COOKIE_KEY = 'CookieKey';
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$optUser = array(
    'resource' => 'customers',
    'filter[email]' => '[' . $email . ']',
    'display' => '[id,email,lastname,firstname,passwd]'
);

$resultUser = ($webService->get($optUser));

$json = json_encode($resultUser);
```

The second and most important thing is to Check the user input

```
// code placeholder

foreach ($resultUser->customers->customer as $info) {
    // Prestashop uses the cookie_key in combination with a salt key. To check the password use the php function: password_verify();
    $salt = substr($info->passwd, strrpos($info->passwd, ':') + 1, 2);
    $ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password) . ':' . $salt;

    // Check if password comparison is true or false
    if (password_verify($password, $info->passwd) == true) {
        session_start();
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'succes';
        $response['message'] = "You did it!";
        setcookie("userId", $info->id);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Wrong password';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

This is how to reproduce the issue to a working example.

What i've used is setting a `cookie` and check if it exists!

Hope this helps!